# Is it appropriate to ask if I'll be offered a full time position after my internship?

Tags: internship, fulltime

So it's my final week at my internship (it's been 6 weeks) and I'm unsure of whether to wait until my boss brings it up or to go ahead and suggest a chat regarding after my internship has ended.

I'm unsure because in the interview, the internship was described as a slow hiring process, and that typically, if all goes well, interns are offered a three month trial and then a years contract. I was offered the internship at the end of the interview and had positive feedback on my work. Interns are taken on every year at the company, and there is only one other intern here too - and she has another internship arranged after this one.

I was just wondering if it's just a little bit cheeky to ask? And although it's none of my bosses concern (and I wouldn't dare mention this either!), I've moved into a spare room specifically for this internship and need to know whether I can move into a new place or move back home (tenancy ends mid August!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say it is cheeky at all. It is a valid question.

A common misconception in interviews is that you are thankful for them giving you a job. The interview is a two way thing. It is just as much for you to determine if the company is the right fit for you as it is for them.

You have valid reasons for asking this question, so ask it.

Personally I'd have no issue asking an interviewer at what point in the internship would I know if there is a full time job or not, so that I can start advertising for a job elsewhere if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Asking them whether they are going to offer you a full time position is a bit cheeky for my taste.

However, it is not cheeky to tell them that being encouraged by the good reviews you have received and being motivated by the good experience that you have had at the firm as an intern, you'd like to follow up on the good reviews and the good experience and ask them if they have made a decision as to whether they are going to make you an offer for a full time position, as your internship draws to its end. You could add that since you already know them, you like working with them and you are looking forward to working with them, a positive answer would great news for you snd spare you the need to look for a full time position..

They may turn you down for business reasons such as their cash position. If so, put plan B in gear: make sure to ask for references and ask them to recommend you .to other firms partners within their network of business partners that could use your services and talent.