# Internship is almost over, need to start hinting at being hired on permanently

Tags: internship, united-states, new-hires

My current internship will be over in just a few months (December). At that time, it's quite possible that I'll be offered a permanent position. If offered the job, I will most likely take it.

Because I *do* want to become a permanent employee, I feel like I should start putting forth specific efforts in order to best ensure that I get offered the job. My concern, however, is that I don't want to come off as if I'm demanding/requesting some kind of early assurance from my boss that he's going to hire me.

My question is: **Is there anything that I can do or say that would be most tactful when attempting to transition from intern to permanent employee?**

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Is it appropriate to ask if I'll be offered a full time position after my internship?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30899/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-if-ill-be-offered-a-full-time-position-after-my-intern) and [How to ask to continue with employer after an internship?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84004/how-to-ask-to-continue-with-employer-after-an-internship/84005#84005)

Comment: Are any of your colleagues interns-turned-permanents that started before you? Maybe they will know of the hints to look for?

Comment: @GrayCygnus If I don't need to ask, then I don't have an interest in doing so. If there are other methods for demonstrating interest, or excitement, in the permanent position, I would prefer to explore those first, before bluntly asking my boss (which I feel would be a one time conversation, as apposed to what could otherwise be a series of actions that speak much more loudly about my interest in the permanent position).

Comment: Just ask. If your employer wants to hire you they won't change their mind because you have asked, and if they do not want to then you have lost nothing.

Comment: The focal point of my post is how to best ensure that I'll be offered the permanent position, specifically when coming from an intern. Should I try to structure my work so that it's dependent upon my presence? Should I make extra efforts in other aspects of my work/interactions with coworkers? etc.

Comment: So... you want the job but you don't want to ask for it? No, subtle hints is **not** the way to go about advancing your career. If you're just wondering how to do a good job in general, that's hopelessly too broad for this site.

Comment: @Dukeling I have no problem asking if there is the possibility of my internship becomes a permanent position. However, unless his answer is black & white, there will most likely still be a great deal of uncertainty, at which point it will be much more difficult for me to bring up again without coming off as unnecessarily persistent. Thus, I am trying to explore other means for "buttering him up", and for maximizing my chances of being kept on.

Comment: Figuring out when to ask might make a good question. 3 months is maybe *a bit* too far ahead of time, but not that much - if they don't offer you a position, now's about the time you should be starting the job search. How long have you been an intern there? Are you currently studying and will you still be studying at the end of the internship (and for how long)?

Comment: @Dukeling I've been here for five months now. I'm still a student, but will have graduated and be ready to take the permanent position, should it be offered to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anything that I can do or say that would be most tactful when
>   attempting to transition from intern to permanent employee?

If you haven't asked your boss already and your nearing the end of the intership period ( like in this case ), there is nothing wrong with asking your boss.  Something along the lines of "*Are there any plans to convert my internship into full time employment?*"

As a matter of fact, the **earlier you know** the plan the better as this gives you more time to plan your next move if they do not intend on bringing you on as a FTE.

You have to get used to asking for what you want as you progress in your career.  If you don't ask, then typically the answer will be no.

Comment: True. Wouldn't this be somewhat to my disadvantage though, since the topic couldn't really be visited again? I mean, I suppose it's good to know ahead of time, as to not get my hopes up, however, unless his answer is anything but absolutely certain, I will most likely want to bring it up again as time gets closer.

Comment: @Charles earlier is better so you have more time to plan your next move if need be.

Comment: So, assume that I do ask this week, and his response is "possibly, I can't say for sure at this point". What then? I'm still exactly where I started, and with no new information. With me being an action-based person, I feel like there's something I should *do*.. if not, then that's fine too.

Comment: @Charles That ( **possibly, I cannot say at this point** ) is actionable information.  It either means your boss isn't sure about *you* or whether or not there will be *an opening* for a FTE.

Comment: There are two things to do given the "possibly" answer. One is to ask the boss if he knows when he is likely to be able to give a more definitive answer. Put that date in your calendar, and do not ask about it until after then. Meanwhile, go ahead with looking for other jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say it is highly probable you are offered a job after your internship then I would recommend you waited for them to do the offer, to avoid as much as possible being taken as too demanding.

However there is nothing wrong in asking. Seems that you are performing well at your position (evidenced by the high chance of being offered a job and your willingness to take it). If you do ask, remember to convey your enthusiast and interest in the company and job, and that you have found it a great fit for you. Also, do it when you see it is more convenient (i.e.: no incoming critical deadlines, or no stressful week), and again I would wait as much as possible before asking myself (maybe 3+ months is a bit earlier, try to wait at least 1 month before).

Besides *asking* the best you can do to ensure that you will indeed be offered the job is to **maintain an excellent performance and attitude**. Nothing speaks better than actions when trying to convince someone. If you have not, try giving "the extra mile" in your tasks now and then, so they can see you are indeed interested beyond just monetary compensation. Also, remember to be polite and respectful to all your coworkers, and not only those you relate to or your immediate superiors; you should treat the janitor with the same respect you should give to anyone else. That is an exemplary attitude and a sign of someone humble and willing to learn.

Just remember, be careful you are not doing this "just to land the job", and as soon as you get it stop being exemplary. Any experienced manager will easily see that you are faking it just to get the job; your attitude should be genuine and that is the tough (rewarding) part of this. However, this is easily achieved if you and the company/job are a good fit to each other, as things tend to flow naturally plus you enjoy it. I hope this is you case and that these words help you get the job, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When your company has an open job offering which applies to your skillset, you can just apply to that position in the same way you would apply to any other job. Just that you would focus your cover letter on what you are already doing for the company.

When there is no job offering, you need to convince people to create one for you.

If you don't know already who makes hiring decisions in your company, find out who it is. Then ask them for an appointment to discuss your future career at the company.